# One liner for push to array only if its not undefined else assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i wrote the following code .is there any one liner for the following ?

```
if (this.selectedUsersToAdd.length) {
  this.selectedUsersToAdd.push(selectedUsersToAdd);
} else {
  this.selectedUsersToAdd = selectedUsersToAdd;
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit to a one liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ternary:

```
this.selectedUsersToAdd.length ? this.selectedUsersToAdd.push(selectedUsersToAdd) : this.selectedUsersToAdd = selectedUsersToAdd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator and assign value of array you want to add if first one is empty or result of `concat` if it's not empty.

```js
let arr = [];
let add = [1, 2];
arr = arr.length ? arr.concat(add) : add;

console.log(arr)
```

In case you want to push whole new array to old one if old one is not empty, then first push new one and return old one.

```js
let arr = [1];
let add = [1, 2];
arr = arr.length ? (arr.push(add), arr) : add;

console.log(arr)
```